# FInding K-mean distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have a database which has 13 features and 10million rows. I wanted to apply k-mean to remove any anomalies. My though was to apply k-mean, create a new column with the distance between the data points and the cluster centroids, and a new column with the mean distance,and if the distance is larger than the mean distance I remove the whole row. But it seems the code I wrote is not working.

Dataset sample:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iB1qjnWQyvoKuN_Pa8Xk4BySzXVTwtUk

```
df = pd.read_csv('Final After Simple Filtering.csv',index_col=None,low_memory=True)


# Dropping columns with low feature importance
del df['AmbTemp_DegC']
del df['NacelleOrientation_Deg']
del df['MeasuredYawError']



#applying kmeans
#applying kmeans
kmeans = KMeans( n_clusters=8)


clusters= kmeans.fit_predict(df)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

distance1 = kmeans.fit_transform(df)

distance2 = distance1.mean()

df['distances']=distance1-distance2

df = df[df['distances'] >=0]


del df['distances']

df.to_csv('/content//drive/My Drive/K TEST.csv', index=False)
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'distances'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
9 frames
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'distances'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    126             raise ValueError(
    127                 "Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies "
--> 128                 "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
    129             )
    130 

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: @Ehrendil I have posted the error at the main post.

Comment: I'd recommend posting a sample of the dataframe as well

Comment: I have added a samply of my dataset to the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a follow up answer for your last question.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
titanic = titanic.copy()
titanic = titanic.dropna()
titanic['age'].plot.hist(
  bins = 50,
  title = "Histogram of the age variable"
)


from scipy.stats import zscore
titanic["age_zscore"] = zscore(titanic["age"])
titanic["is_outlier"] = titanic["age_zscore"].apply(
  lambda x: x <= -2.5 or x >= 2.5
)
titanic[titanic["is_outlier"]]


ageAndFare = titanic[["age", "fare"]]
ageAndFare.plot.scatter(x = "age", y = "fare")


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
ageAndFare = scaler.fit_transform(ageAndFare)
ageAndFare = pd.DataFrame(ageAndFare, columns = ["age", "fare"])
ageAndFare.plot.scatter(x = "age", y = "fare")


from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
outlier_detection = DBSCAN(
  eps = 0.5,
  metric="euclidean",
  min_samples = 3,
  n_jobs = -1)
clusters = outlier_detection.fit_predict(ageAndFare)

clusters


from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('Accent')
ageAndFare.plot.scatter(
  x = "age",
  y = "fare",
  c = clusters,
  cmap = cmap,
  colorbar = False
)
```

[image]

See this link for all details.

https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/outlier-detection-with-scikit-learn/

I have never heard of 'Local Outlier Factor' before today.  When I Googled it, I got some information that seems to indicate that it is a derivative of DBSCAN.  Finally, I think my first answer is actually the best way to detect outliers.  DBSCAN is clustering algo that happens to find outliers, which are really considered 'noise'.  I don't think the primary purpose of DBSCAN is anomaly detection, but rather clustering.  In conclusion, it takes a bit of skill to choose hyper-parameters correctly.  Also, DBSCAN can be slow on very large datasets, as it implicitly needs to compute the empirical density for each sample point, leading  to  a  quadratic  worst-case  time  complexity, which is quite slow on large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You: I wanted to apply k-mean to remove any anomalies.

Actually, KMeas will detect anomalies and include them in the nearest cluster.  The loss function is the minimum sum of squared distances from each point to its assigned cluster centroid.  If you want to kick out outliers, consider using a z-score methodology.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# import your data
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\your_file.csv)

# get only numerics
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
newdf = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)

df = newdf

# count rows in DF before kicking out records with z-score over 3
df.shape

# handle NANs
df = df.fillna(0)


from scipy import stats
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
df.shape


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3))
from scipy import stats
df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]

# count rows in DF before kicking out records with z-score over 3
df.shape
```

In addition, take a look at these links when you have some free time.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/effect-of-outliers-on-k-means-algorithm-using-python-7ba85821ea23

https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/outliers/

Comment: I've been reading on K-mean for a couple of days and most of what I read is it not meant to be used for anomaly detection and there are way better methods to do so. Unfortunately, part of my final year project is to compare Isolation Forest, Elliptic Envelope and K-mean for outlier removal. Thank you very much for your help as well.

Comment: Take a look at DBSCAN too.  This algo will help you find actual outliers, which I believe are defined as 'noise'.  https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/outlier_detection.html & https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter_selection.html

Comment: If I find a hard time to remove outliers from my dataset using K-mean, would it be better to use DBSCAN or Local Outlier Factor (LOF) ?